# How to change time format in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I want to change  the date format of '20100101' into '2010-01-01' in sqlite.

```
SELECT  strftime('%Y-%m-%d','20100101');
```

But the output is `5032-02-09`,how can i get `2010-01-01` with sqlite command?

Comment: That ('20100101') is not a valid SQLite date string. SQLite does not have a 'datetime' data type and uses strings to store the standard 'yyyy-mm-dd' format dates. It is explained here: [www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: All the time data in the sqlite already is in  the form of 'yyyymmdd',how can i change it into 'yyyy-mm-dd'?

Comment: Think of it as a string not a time while you put it in the correct format. It is just string manipulation of taking substrings and concatinating them with dashes. See the manual here, it has an example that will do what you want: [Working with strings in SQLite](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg08.htm) .

Comment: @RyanVincent Actually, `20100101` is a valid date, as a Julian day number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the string is not in one of [SQLite's supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you cannot use the built-in [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

You have to use plain string operations: extract the fields, and insert hyphens between them:

```
SELECT substr(MyDate, 1, 4) || '-' ||
       substr(MyDate, 5, 2) || '-' ||
       substr(MyDate, 7, 2)
FROM (SELECT '20100101' AS MyDate)
```